# Validate Number or string

Tags: excel, vba

Quick question: I have a cell that can have as value or a number or the string "NN"

I wrote this line of code:

```
If Not IsNumeric(Cells(c, 64)) Or Cells(c, 64) <> "NN" Then
    errCell.Value = "Wrong Div"
    errCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    GoTo Boucle
 End If
```

I apply to a cell which is a number But I get an error...
Any lead would be great
Thank you

Comment: And you get the error where? And the error msg?

Comment: I have a the `Wrong Div` message ... basically the macro compiles well  but it should not specify this error since the cell is a number

Comment: `Or` >> `And` should fix it

Comment: Of course it should, the right side of the OR returs true so it writes "Wrong Div", maybe you want to replace OR by AND

Comment: was so simple... damn myself... thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a logic error - as it stands the error message is always shown. Try:

```
If Not IsNumeric(Cells(c, 64)) AND Cells(c, 64) <> "NN"
```